# Kill child process spawned with execl without making it zombie

Tags: c, linux

I need to spawn a long-running child process and then kill it from the parent code. At the moment I do like this:

```
int PID = fork();
if (PID == 0) {
  execl("myexec", "myexec", nullptr);
  perror("ERROR");
  exit(1);
}
// do something in between and then:
kill(PID, SIGKILL);
```

This does the job in the sense that the child process is stopped, but then it remains as a zombie. I tried to completely remove it by adding:

```
kill(getpid(), SIGCHLD);
```

to no avail. I must be doing something wrong but I can't figure out what, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can't you `wait` the child from the parent ?

Comment: No, the child process is meant to run indefinitely until the parent kills it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
kill(getpid(), SIGCHLD);
```

Presto. No zombie.

By ignoring SIGCHLD we tell the kernel we don't care about exit codes so the zombies just go away immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You have been answered with:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

to ignore the signal sent to the parent when a child dies.  This is an old mechanism to avoid zombies, but zombies are your friends, as my answer will explain.

The zombies are not a bug, but a feature of the system.  They are there to complete the `fork(2)`, `wait(2)`, `exit(2)`, `kill(2)` group of system calls.

When you `wait(2)` for a child to die, the kernel tests if there's a child running with the characteristics you state in the `wait(2)`.  If it exists, the `wait(2)` will block, because the `wait(2)` system call is the one used in unix to give the parent the exit status of the waited child.  If you use `wait()` and you have done no `fork()` a new child previously, `wait()` should give you an error, because you are calling wait with no fork (i'll stop boldening the system calls in this discussion from here on)  but what happens if the parent **did a fork** but the child died before the parent was capable of making a wait.  Should this be taken as an error?  No.  The system maintains the process table entry for the child proces, until one of two things happen:  The parent dies (then all children processess get orphaned, being adopted by process id `1` ---`init`/`systemd`--- which is continously blocked in wait calls; or the parent does a wait, in which case the status of one (or the one requested) of the children is reported.

So in a proper usage of the system, it is possible (or necessary) to make a wait call for each fork you make.  if you do more waits than forks, you get errors... if you make more forks than waits, you get zombies.  In order to compensate this, your code should be changed to make the appropiate wait call.

```
kill(PID, SIGINT); /* don't use SIGKILL in the first time, give time to your process to arrange its last will before dying */
res = waitpid(PID, &status, 0);
```

And this will allow the child to die normally.  The child is going to die, because you killed it (except if the child has decided to ignore the signal you send to it)

The reason for no race condition here (the child could die *before* is is `wait()`ed for) is the zombie process.  Zombie processes are not proper processes, they don't accept signals, it is impossible to kill them, because they are dead already (no pun here ;)).  They only occupy the process table slot, but no resource is allocated to them.  When a parent does a wait call, if there's a zombie, it will be freed and the accounting info will be transferred to the parent (this is how the accounting is done), including the exit status, and if there isn't (because it died prematurely and you had invoked the above behaviour) you will get an error from wait, and the accounting info will be tranferred to init/systemd, which will cope for this. If you decide to ignore the `SIGCHLD` signal, you are cancelling the production of zombies, but the accounting is being feed in the wron way to `init`/`systemd`, and not accounted in the parent. (no such process can be waited for)  you cannot distinguish if the wait fails because the child process died or because you didn't spawn it correctly. More is to come.

Let's say that the child cannot exec a new program and it dies (calling exit()).  When you kill it, nothing happens, as there's no target process (well, you should receive an error from kill call, but I assume you are not interested in the kill result, as it is irrelevant for this case, you are interested in the `status` of the child, or how did the child died.  This means you need to wait for it. if you get a normal exit, with a status of `1`, (as you did an exit in  case exec() fails) you will know that the child was not able to exec (you still need to distinguish if the `1` exit code was produced by the child or by the program later run by the child).  If you successfully killed the child, you should get a status telling you that the child was killed with signal (the one you sent) and you will know that your code is behaving properly.

In case you don't want to block your parent process in the wait system call (well, your child program could have decided to ignore signals and the kill had no effect), then you can substitute the above by this:

```
kill(PID, SIGINT);
res = waitpid(PID, &status, WNOHANG);
```

that will not block the parent, in the case the child program has decided to ignore the signal you send to it.  In this case, if wait returns `-1` and `errno` value `EINTR`, then you know that your child has decided to ignore the signal you sent to it, and you need help from the operator (or be more drastic, e.g. killing it with `SIGKILL`).

A good approach should be

```
void alarm_handler()
{
}

...

kill(PID, SIGINT); /* kill it softly (it's your child, man!!) */
void *saved = signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
alarm(3);          /* put an awakener, you will be interrupted in 3s. */
res = waitpid(PID, &status, 0);
signal(SIGALRM, saaved); /* restore the previous signal handler */
if (res == -1 && errno == EINTR) {
    /* we where interrupted by the alarm, and child didn't die. */
    kill(PID, SIGKILL); /* be more rude */
}
```